# What is the maximum entropy distribution over the integers

Tags: probability-distributions, it.information-theory, entropy

Let $μ=0,σ>0$. What is the maximum entropy distribution over the integers with mean $μ$ and variance $σ^2$?

Is [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) a maximum entropy distribution? Is there a closed-form expression to compute the entropy of this distribution?

Comment: The wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution already tells you that it must be of the form $p_n= c e^{an-bn^2}$, and it would seem $a,b,c$ are determined by your requirements on $\mu,\sigma$.

Comment: Noting that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \exp(-bn^2) = \theta_3(0,\exp(-b))$ (a Jacobi Theta function), you want $a=0$, $c = 1/\theta_3(0,\exp(-b))$, and $$\dfrac{d}{db} \theta_3(0, \exp(-b)) = -\sigma^2 \theta_3(0,\exp(-b))$$

Comment: Could you refer to any book or article on those results? Many thanks!

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) and links there.